# porque me cambia la variable si solo estoy cambiando un elemento

Tags: python, lista, variables

Estoy intentando escribir código para jugar al ahorcado cada vez que adivinan una letra me la cambian en la lista `guess` pero cuando adivinan la siguiente solo aparece esa letra en la lista, me borra las anteriores.

```
import random

IMÁGENES_AHORCADO = ['''
    +---+
    |   |
        |
        |
        |
        |
 =========''', '''
    +---+
    |   |
    O   |
        |
        |
        |
 =========''', '''
    +---+
    |   |
    O   |
    |   |
        |
        |
 =========''', '''
    +---+
    |   |
    O   |
   /|   |
        |
        |
 =========''', '''
    +---+
    |   |
    O   |
   /|\  |
        |
        |
 =========''', '''
    +---+
    |   |
    O   |
   /|\  |
   /    |
        |
 =========''', '''
    +---+
    |   |
    O   |
   /|\  |
   / \  |
        |
 =========''']


palabras ='hormiga babuino tejon murcielago oso castor camello gato almeja cobra pantera coyote cuervo ciervo perro burro pato aguila huron zorro rana cabra ganso halcon leon lagarto llama topo mono alce raton mula salamandra nutria buho panda loro paloma piton conejo carnero rata cuervo rinoceronte salmon foca tiburon oveja mofeta perezoso serpiente araña cigüeña cisne tigre sapo trucha pavo tortuga comadreja ballena lobo wombat cebra'.split()
palabra = random.choice(palabras)

intentos=0
letras_incorrectas=list()
print(palabra)
print(len(IMÁGENES_AHORCADO))

while intentos <= len(IMÁGENES_AHORCADO):

    letra = input('Adivina una letra: ')

    guess = list()

    while len(guess) < len(palabra):
        guess.append('__')

    if letra in palabra:

        lista=list()
        for x in palabra:       
            lista.append(x)

        indices=list()
        indice=0

        for y in lista:
            if y == letra:
                indice=lista.index(y,indice)
                indices.append(indice)
                print (indices)
                for i in indices:
                    guess[i]=letra  
                    print('1',guess)

                try:
                    indice=lista.index(y,indice+1)
                    indices.append(indice)
                    for i in indices:
                        guess[i]=letra 
                        print('2',guess) 
                except:
                    continue

        print(IMÁGENES_AHORCADO[len(letras_incorrectas)])
        print('3',guess)
        print('letras incorrectas:',letras_incorrectas)

    else:

        letras_incorrectas.append(letra)
        print(IMÁGENES_AHORCADO[len(letras_incorrectas)])
        print('4',guess)
        print('letras incorrectas:',letras_incorrectas)
        intentos+=1
```

Comment: Porque reasignas a `guess` una lista vacía que llenas con "__" **en cada iteración del `while`**, debes crear la lista fuera del while, antes del ciclo y una sola vez.

Comment: Muchas gracias, la he sacado fuera del ciclo como haz dicho y ha funcionado!